Making a category less concrete
Sometimes, one starts with a concrete category and sets out finding an equivalent category that is less concrete.  By a concrete category, I mean one whose objects are sets, morphisms are functions,  morphism composites are function composites, and identity morphisms are identity functions.
One example that I have in mind is the so-called de Vries duality for compact Hausdorff spaces.  Here the category KHaus of compact Hausdorff spaces is found to be equivalent to that of so-called de Vries algebras dV.  Now dV has sets as objects and functions as morphisms, but its morphsm composition is not the function composition.  In this sense, dV is less concrete than KHaus, even though dV was constructed a posteriori.  I would imagine that dV is aesthetically more pleasing in some ways than KHaus, and that is the trade-off of not being concrete.
Host of other examples are found in, e.g., Bice and Kubis's paper (Bice and Kubis's paper), where they identified many categories  equivalent to full subcategories of Top.  These categories still have sets as objects but have partial functions and relations as morphisms.  They created these non-concrete categories so that $F(X)$ is countable even when $X$ is not, where $F$ is a functor from a full subcategory of Top that is part of an equivalence.
I am looking for other examples of non-concrete categories that are constructed to be equivalent to long-known concrete categories.  I am aware that it's trivial to construct such categories per se, but I am looking for those in the literature that have some advantage (e.g., aesthetics, cardinality, ...) when compared to the original concrete categories.

$\DeclareMathOperator{Aut}{Aut}$Let me give a half-baked example.
Consider a fixed group $G$. We introduce students to $G$-sets as sets $X$ together with an action $G\times X \rightarrow X$ satisfying some axioms. Morphisms of $G$-sets are $G$-equivariant functions $X\rightarrow Y$.
Another viewpoint is that $G$-sets are sets $X$ together with a group homomorphism $G\rightarrow \Aut(X)$ and maps are functions $X \rightarrow Y$ which are somehow compatible with these homomorphisms. Arguably the cleanest way to state these compatibilities is via categorical language. There is a category $BG$, which has one object $\ast$ and whose endomorphism monoid $(BG(\ast,\ast),\circ) = (G,\cdot)$ is given by the group. A $G$-set is then nothing but a functor $BG\rightarrow \mathsf{Set}$, a morphism of $G$-sets is nothing but a natural transformation between them.
This is very nice for several reasons:
a) it is immediately clear what kind of categorical constructions $G$-sets admit. For example: as a presheaf category it has limits and colimits and they are computed pointwise.
b) This construction immediately generalizes to an extend that we can talk about $G$-objects in any category $\mathscr{C}$. With the usual definition we would first have to think about how to realize the group $G$ as an object of the category $\mathscr{C}$. This is doable (and equivalent) in many instances, but sometimes it is not.
c) Nobody forces us to assume $G$ is a group. We can do the same for any monoid $M$ and define $M$-sets via some category $BM$. Or we can consider some arbitrary indexing category $\mathcal{I}$ instead of $BG$. Just thinking of a functor $\mathcal{I} \rightarrow\mathscr{C}$ as some sort of generalized action can be very handy.
Why do I consider this a half-baked example? It is debatable, whether this counts as a non-concrete category. From a pedagogical viewpoint, functors and natural transformations may be more abstract than sets with structure and structure preserving maps. But on the other hand the forgetful functor to sets is pretty clear. (Any category equivalent to a concrete category is concrete, so a posteriori this might not be that much of an issue...)
